# Linking against an external object file (.o) with autoconf

Tags: makefile, gnu, autotools, configure, autoconf

For work purposes I need to link against an object file generated by another program and found in its folder, the case is that I did not find information about this kind of linkage. I think that if I hardcode the paths and put the `name-of-obj.o` in front of the `package_LDADD` variable should work, but the case is that I don't want to do it that way.

If the object is not found I want the configure to fail and tell the user that the `name-of-obj.o` is missing.

I tried by using `AC_LIBOBJ([name-of-obj.o])` but this will try to find in the root directory a name-of-obj.c and compile it.

Any tip or solution around this issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

> I need to link against an object file generated by another program and
>   found in its folder

What you describe is a very unusual requirement, not among those that the Autotools are designed to handle cleanly or easily.  In particular, Autoconf has no mechanisms specifically applicable to searching for bare object files, as opposed to libraries, and Automake has no particular automation around including such objects when it links.  Nevertheless, these tools do have enough general purpose functionality to do what you want; it just won't be as tidy as you might like.

> I think that if I hardcode the paths and put the
>   `name-of-obj.o` in front of the `package_LDADD` variable should work, but
>   the case is that I don't want to do it that way.

I take it that it is the "hardcode the paths" part that you want to avoid.  Adding an item to an appropriate `LDADD` variable is not negotiable; it is the right way to get your object included in the link.

> If the object is not found I want the configure to fail and tell the
>   user that the name-of-obj.o is missing.

Well, then, the key thing appears to be to get `configure` to perform a search for your object file.  Autoconf does not have a built-in mechanism to perform such a search, but it's just a macro-based shell-script generator, so you can write such a search in shell script + Autoconf, maybe something like this:

```
AC_MSG_CHECKING([for name-of-obj.o])
OTHER_LOCATION=
for my_dir in
    /some/location/other_program/src
    /another/location/other_program.12345/src
    $srcdir/../relative/location/other_program/src; do
  AS_IF([test -r "${my_dir}/name-of-obj.o"], [
    # optionally, perform any desired test to check that the object is usable
    # ... perhaps one using AC_LINK_IFELSE ...
    # if it passes, then
    OTHER_LOCATION=${my_dir}
    break
  ])
done

# Check whether the object was in fact discovered, and act appropriately
AS_IF([test "x${OTHER_LOCATION}" = x], [
  # Not found
  AC_MSG_RESULT([not found])
  AC_MSG_ERROR([Cannot configure without name-of-obj.o])
], [
  AC_MSG_RESULT([${OTHER_LOCATION}/name-of-obj.o])
  AC_SUBST([OTHER_LOCATION])
])
```

That's functional, but of course you could embellish, such as by providing for the package builder to specify a location to use via a command-line argument (`AC_ARG_WITH(...)`).  And if you want to do this for multiple objects, then you would probably want to wrap up at least some of that into a custom macro.

The Automake side is much less involved.  To get the object linked, you just need to add it to the appropriate `LDADD` variable, using the output variable created by the above, such as:

```
foo_LDADD = $(OTHER_LOCATION)/name-of-obj.o
```

Note that if you're building just one program target then you can use the general `LDADD` instead of `foo_LDADD`, but note that by default these are alternatives not complements.

---

With that said, this is a bad idea overall.  If you want to link something that is not part of your project, then you should get it from an installed library.  That can be a local, custom-built library, of course, so long as it is a library, not a bare object file, and it is installed.  It can be a static library if you don't want to rely on or distribute a separate shared library.

On the other hand, if your project is part of a larger build, then the best approach is probably to integrate it into that build, maybe as a subproject.  It would still be best to link a library instead of a bare object file, but in a subproject context it might make sense to use a lib that was not installed to the build system.  In conjunction with a command-line argument that tells it where to find the wanted lib, this could make the needed Autoconf code much cleaner and clearer.